# Fail to execute command on startup

Tags: 20.04, cron, systemd, services, execute-command

I want to run a simple command after my ubuntu starts up and network services are established (it should do so no matter wheater I'm logged in or not)

If I run the command manually, it start's up the enclosed applications: `confluent local services start`. So it works at least with my user.

Questions:

- How can I run the command on system startup (after network is esablished)?
- To any solutions suggested, how can I monitor if the solution really executes?

What I've tried so far:

- **crontab**: `sudo crontab e` and added `@reboot confluent local services start`. This line is erased every time I reboot the system.
- **system service**: I've added the command to a sh script under /usr/local/bin/confluent-startup.sh. Then I've created the service file in `/etc/systemd/system/confluent-local.service` This file would hold the following content:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=starting local confluent
  After=network.service
  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/confluent-local-start.sh
  Type=oneshot
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

I've reloaded the services

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable confluent-local.service
```

After rebooting, I see the service enabled invoking: `systemctl list-unit-files --type service -all`. But running `confluent local services status` would show me that all services are still down. Why does it work manually but not with systemd? (FYI: I've change rights on the service and on the script to full access: 777 (yes, I know... It's just for testing))

Any clue?

Comment: What do you get from “systemctl status confluent-local.service”?

Comment: @PonJar 
confluent-local.service - starting local confluent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/confluent-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-10-10 09:51:11 UTC; 1h 7min ago
   Main PID: 648 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)


status=203: often execute if script is not executable?!? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950/systemd-status-203-exec-error-when-creating-new-service

Comment: It’s generally better to add this kind of output to your question. Looks like you have clues to a fix. If you solve it you can answer your own question which will help others in the future. Let us know how you get on